# Ionic - plugins not being added to ios folder

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Starting with a fresh ionic install and then adding plugins, they are not added to the ios folder. I tried `ionic prepare` which results in `add to body class: platform-ios` but it does not add the plugins to the ios directory and results in this error:

```
CompileXIB moodtracker/Resources/DatePicker.xib
cd /Users/tomchambers/projects/moodtrackerApp/platforms/ios
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/tomchambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/tomchambers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/tomchambers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/tomchambers/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin"
export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --errors --warnings --notices --module moodtracker --minimum-deployment-target 6.0 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/tomchambers/projects/moodtracker/platforms/ios/build/moodtracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/moodtracker.build/DatePicker-PartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/tomchambers/projects/moodtrackerApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/moodtracker.app/DatePicker.nib /Users/tomchambers/projects/moodtrackerApp/platforms/ios/moodtracker/Resources/DatePicker.xib
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/tomchambers/projects/moodtrackerApp/platforms/ios/moodtracker/Resources/DatePicker.xib: error: Interface Builder could not open the document DatePicker.xib" because it does not exist.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CpResource moodtracker/Resources/CDVNotification.bundle build/emulator/moodtracker.app/CDVNotification.bundle
    CompileXIB moodtracker/Resources/DatePicker.xib
(2 failures)
Error: /Users/tomchambers/projects/moodtrackerApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

The only way I've found to make it work is to completely delete the ios build folder and do `cordova platform add ios` which will readd it with the plugins. This seems very inconvenient.

Comment: Have you updated Cordova but not updated the Cordova version of the project? I've had issues when they were not in sync. Update project: `cordova platform update ios`.